# Cannot disable sorting in datagridview

Tags: winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have problem with `datagridview`.

At start I disabling sorting in column(`dictionaryDataGridView_ColumnAdded` and in designer)

When I doubleclick at columnheader sorting enables.

And it works.

When I doubleclick again at columnheader disabling.

And when I check SortMode of this column is NotSortable.

That is great.

But, when now I change value in row, it sorting my column.

It's very stressful for user, which lost from sight his row, and for me because I can't abort this sorting.

In `dictionaryDataGridView_CellEndEdit` I see that's `SortGlyphDirection` is set to `None`, and `SortMode` is set to `NotSortable`, so It'couldn't sort, but sorts.

Does anyone know why is that? Is it bug in datagridview, or I miss something?

```
private void dictionaryDataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        var column = dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (column.SortMode != DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic)
        {

            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
            dictionaryDataGridView.Sort(this.dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            this.dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
            this.dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
    }
}

private void dictionaryDataGridView_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}

private void dictionaryDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var aaa = this.dictionaryDataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer. It can't be done:

http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-data-controls-databinding/datagridview-how-to-stop--cancel-sorting-26732.shtml